# How do you use the Wikipedia API?

Tags: c#, api, unity-game-engine, wikipedia

How does the Wikipedia API work, and how the endpoints are created? Is the Wikipedia API the same as other APIs or has special differences? I am trying to grab the introduction of a Wikipedia article like this content from the Unity Wikipedia article:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unity_(game_engine)

"Unity is a cross-platform game engine developed by Unity Technologies, first announced and released in June 2005 at Apple Worldwide Developers Conference as a Mac OS X game engine. The engine has since been gradually extended to support a variety of desktop, mobile, console and virtual reality platforms. It is particularly popular for iOS and Android mobile game development and is considered easy to use for beginner developers and is popular for indie game development.[5]

The engine can be used to create three-dimensional (3D) and two-dimensional (2D) games, as well as interactive simulations and other experiences.[6][7] The engine has been adopted by industries outside video gaming, such as film, automotive, architecture, engineering, construction, and the United States Armed Forces.[8]"

It seems there is a lack of resources on how to use the Wikipedia API in Unity because I have searched for a long time to solve this problem.

Comment: Unity is a game engine....but it does run C#/.NET, and there are ways to consume HTTP API's from C# and .NET. That's what you should look into, rather than being hyperfocused on Unity.

Comment: I suppose the Wikipedia api is well documented, what exactly was the problem when you tried to use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a typical REST API.

[UnityWebRequest](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest.html) is the current way of talking to these kinds of sites/APIs in the Unity idiom. You can issue standard GET, POST, and PUT requests with it.

All of Wikipedia's API documentation including what appears to be Swagger API documentation is available via https://en.wikipedia.org/api/

If you're not sure how to put these two things together, there are a lot of tutorials out there on accessing a REST API from Unity. I'm not going to play favorites with that one.

While you're learning how to use UnityWebRequest to talk to a REST API, instead of slamming Wikipedia with endless requests and potentially getting put on Santa's naughty list, you should use something like https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/ or even [stand up a quick ASP.NET Core API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/min-web-api) on your localhost to learn how they work.

By the way, most folks use something like Insomnia or Postman to figure out which end of the connection is busted.